# AutoFocus to next field after selecting a value in react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am using react-select, where after selecting a value from the dropdown i.e on clicking enter key, I want the focus to move to next field. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is that you need ? https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-select

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain how it worked? And what if I would want to use arrow keys like "Down" key?

Comment: late but hope you got my solution, anyway will explain it in answer if it solves your need.